TypeScript: Auto assign readonly properites?
So i've been doing this with TypeScript classes, and I just sort of realized that this is not the way MOST people write TS Classes (Specifically this is for Page Object Models in Playwright for Test Automation.
Anyways my class will typically look something like this:
import { BasePage } from "@pages/base.page";

export default class TestPage extends BasePage {
  public readonly someButton = this.page
    .getByRole("button")
    .filter({ hasText: "A Cool Button" });

  async open() {
    await super.open("/some/url");
  }

}

Obviously this is a super simple example. But In these classes I never declare a constructor. But I can freely use the readonly property (in this case someButton via this.someButton and I can access the property members and any public functions on a class instance just fine.
However even in Playwrights own PoM solution: https://playwright.dev/docs/pom#implementation
They may add readonly properties, but actually still assign them like you normally would in JavaScript via this.something = some-locator
How am I able to get away with not having a constructor, and assigning the values on the readonly properties without a constructor and still use them?
My base page looks like this btw:
import type { Page } from "@playwright/test";

export abstract class BasePage {
  constructor(public readonly page: Page) {}

  /**
   * navigates to url
   * @param path - url path
   */
  async open(path: string) {
    await this.page.goto(path);
  }
}


JS supports class fields natively. The readonly will get removed but depending on your settings the above code will emit to JS nearly as-is (see this playground link and look at the JS window). This is equivalent to having the property set/defined in the constructor more or less, so if TS is targeting old versions of JS you could see that too as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what am I missing?

You can initialize your fieds the way you do it, and it's perfectly fine. After compilation they're inlined to constructor's body anyway. It's a matter of preference, but keep in mind, that initialization in constructor body will overwrite field initializations.
Also initializing in constructor will allow you to assign dynamic value, basing on constructor's parameter
Here's another stackoverflow thread with a nice example: Typescript class properties initialization order

They are not necessarily inlined to the constructor's body, unless you are downleveling. JS supports class fields.

I guess why do some people assign locators for example in the constructor vs using just a class field?
